# How to add multiple new columns in pandas data frame without assigning their names manually?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings that I want to be the names of the new columns I want to add to the data frame.

```
for i in len(range(col_name_lis)):
    name = col_name_lis[i]
    merged_df.insert(col_len, name , "")
```

but this gives me this error: `'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the order of len(range(...)) to range(len(...)):

```
col_name_list = ["column 1", "column 2", "column 3"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(col_name_list)):
    name = col_name_list[i]
    df[name] = ""
```

Better yet, use a shorthand for list iteration:

```
col_name_list = ["column 1", "column 2", "column 3"]
for name in col_name_list:
    df[name] = ""
```

Comment: it worked, thank you.

Comment: Great! If you could accept this as the correct answer, I'd appreciate it.